# How to integrate FreshDesk in Ionic application on a specific page?

Tags: ionic-framework, freshdesk

I am working on an Ionic application and want to integrate FreshDesk into a page. I have tried adding the below code under the Head tag. Can anyone please help on this?

```
<script>
    window.fwSettings={ 'widget_id':82000002644 };
    !function(){
        if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){
            var n = function(){
                n.q.push(arguments)
            };
            n.q=[], window.FreshworksWidget=n
        }
    }()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ind-widget.freshworks.com/widgets/82000002644.js' async defer></script>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?